# How to receive data of below mentioned type and extract it

Tags: php, function, parameters, controller, data-processing

I am trying insert the values that has been continuously provided by the data provider and store it into table . The below mentioned is the format:

```
GO XXX,YYY,ZZZ=Ss
            %<QUOTE symbol="XXX" name="testname" exchange="OTHER" basecode="5" pointvalue="1.0" tickincrement="1" ddfexchange="k" lastupdate="20171212095542" mode="R"><SESSION day="B" timestamp="20171212104600" open="67" high="67" low="64" last="64" previous="59" volume="49000" numtrades="3" pricevolume="322.70" id="combined"/><SESSION day="A" timestamp="20171211000000" last="59" id="previous"/></QUOTE>
            %<QUOTE symbol="YYY" name="testname2" exchange="OTHER" basecode="0" pointvalue="1.0" tickincrement="1" ddfexchange="k" lastupdate="20171212095542" mode="R"><SESSION day="B" timestamp="20171212102000" open="169" high="169" low="161" last="169" previous="169" volume="60309" numtrades="6" pricevolume="1009.82" id="combined"/><SESSION day="A" timestamp="20171211000000" last="169" id="previous"/></QUOTE>
            %<QUOTE symbol="ZZZ" name="testname3" exchange="OTHER" basecode="9" pointvalue="1.0" tickincrement="1" ddfexchange="k" lastupdate="20171212095542" mode="R"><SESSION day="B" timestamp="20171212105500" open="8" high="8" low="6" last="6" previous="8" volume="9799179" numtrades="22" pricevolume="7013.11" id="combined"/><SESSION day="A" timestamp="20171211000000" last="8" id="previous"/></QUOTE>
```

How to pass this data to controller function and extract each and every values such as 'symbol','name' etc...?

Please help me to solve this...

Comment: If you strip off the % at the front, it should give you XML, then something like SimpleXML should easily extract the data.

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SimpleXML (after removing the % - assuming this is part of the data), you can easily get at the attributes...

```
$data = <<< XML
GO XXX,YYY,ZZZ=Ss
            %<QUOTE symbol="XXX" name="testname" exchange="OTHER" basecode="5" pointvalue="1.0" tickincrement="1" ddfexchange="k" lastupdate="20171212095542" mode="R"><SESSION day="B" timestamp="20171212104600" open="67" high="67" low="64" last="64" previous="59" volume="49000" numtrades="3" pricevolume="322.70" id="combined"/><SESSION day="A" timestamp="20171211000000" last="59" id="previous"/></QUOTE>
            %<QUOTE symbol="YYY" name="testname2" exchange="OTHER" basecode="0" pointvalue="1.0" tickincrement="1" ddfexchange="k" lastupdate="20171212095542" mode="R"><SESSION day="B" timestamp="20171212102000" open="169" high="169" low="161" last="169" previous="169" volume="60309" numtrades="6" pricevolume="1009.82" id="combined"/><SESSION day="A" timestamp="20171211000000" last="169" id="previous"/></QUOTE>
            %<QUOTE symbol="ZZZ" name="testname3" exchange="OTHER" basecode="9" pointvalue="1.0" tickincrement="1" ddfexchange="k" lastupdate="20171212095542" mode="R"><SESSION day="B" timestamp="20171212105500" open="8" high="8" low="6" last="6" previous="8" volume="9799179" numtrades="22" pricevolume="7013.11" id="combined"/><SESSION day="A" timestamp="20171211000000" last="8" id="previous"/></QUOTE>

XML;

preg_match_all("/%<QUOTE(.*?)<\/QUOTE>/", $data, $list);
foreach ( $list[0] as $item )  {
    $item = ltrim($item, "%");
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($item);
    echo (string)$xml['exchange'].PHP_EOL;
    foreach ( $xml->SESSION as $session )   {
        echo $session['day'].'-'.$session['timestamp'].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The above code outputs...

```
OTHER
B-20171212104600
A-20171211000000
OTHER
B-20171212102000
A-20171211000000
OTHER
B-20171212105500
A-20171211000000
```

I've updated the code with your new data structure, I'm using regular expressions - which I'm not a huge fan of, but this should extract just the components you need.  It uses the same code structure once it's extracted each individual item as before.

To insert the data into a database, you need to look into something like PDO and how to add data to a database (anything like https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dml will help).

Answer (score 0):

Hi please take a look at the official PHP documentation for simpleXML: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php

I created a little snipped, which should get you started: https://eval.in/918963

```
$string = '<QUOTE symbol="XXX" name="name_xxx" exchange="testdata" basecode="C" pointvalue="1.0" tickincrement="1" ddfexchange="U" lastupdate="20171212095542" mode="R">
<SESSION day="B" timestamp="20171212104600" open="67" high="67" low="64" last="64" previous="59" volume="49000" numtrades="3" pricevolume="0000" id="combined"/>
<SESSION day="A" timestamp="20171211000000" last="59" id="previous"/>
</QUOTE>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

//Get all QUOTE attributes
print_r($xml->attributes());

//Get the first SESSION
print_r($xml->SESSION[0]);

//Get all attributes of SESSION[0]
print_r($xml->SESSION[0]->attributes());

//Get a specific attribute of SESSION[0]
print_r($xml->SESSION[0]->attributes()->day);
```